# Image from WPF project's resource stopped showing

Tags: c#, wpf

I added some images as resources to my WPF project, changed their Build Action to `Resource` in Solution Explorer and added them to my Main Window like this:

```
<Image ... Source="Resources/user.png"/>
```

Everything was working until I added and removed one project from my solution, then these images stopped showing both in design and runtime. The `<Image Source/>` tag in XAML editor and the Error List now show the message:

> Could not find a part of the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Resources\user.png".

I tried restarting Visual Studio and the computer, and also cleaned and rebuilt it, but I still don't get the images.

Comment: Without looking at the project, it sounds like the resource was in the project you removed from the solution

Comment: @TonyVitabile I doubled checked, the resource is in the correct project

Comment: Try to *Restart* your Visual Studio. Or *Clean* and *Rebuild* your solution.

Comment: Are you sure the URI is correct? Did you rebuild the solution after removing the project?

Comment: @user2946329 and TonyVitabile, I tried that as well, I've edited my question to include this info.

Comment: Did you copy & paste the message in your question from visual studio or did you type it in? Because the path ought to read "C:\Program Files (x86)..." -- notice the space between "Files" and "(x86)", which is missing in your question. Also, are you really working on your project in the visual studio executable directory? Not a good idea if you are.  The code should be in a project folder well away from either of the Program Files folders.  The image should be in a subfolder of that folder.

Comment: @Tony Vitable I have the same problem, and of course I'm working in my Projects own directory. Was wondering why visual studio has the crazy idea of looking for my Image in its own directory?

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt: You got me. If you ever figure it out, please let me know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `<Image Source="" />`, the `Source` is relative to the XAML file path. The XAML file was on the root, and I moved it to a `View` folder. I didn't know about this until I read this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552618/how-to-reference-image-resources-in-xaml#comment-26663141).

The images are stored in a `Resources` folder inside the project, so in this case the `Source` property must start with a forward slash to point it to root, like this:

```xml
<Image ... Source="/Resources/user.png"/>
```

Comment: If I do that, visual studio assumes with "root" I mean C:/ and of course doesnt find my Resource folder there. Any ideas?