# C# WPF Resource Image (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a picture in my Resource of a project.
Now, which source do I have to set in the image properties? 
Should I use this one i.e. C:\Users\user\Docs\Project\Resources\image.jpg

(I'm using Visual Studio and have a C# WPF project)

Comment: You cannot assign it as a direct link. Take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552618/how-to-reference-image-resources-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

Set the resources buildaction to resource and don't copy to Output Directory

I made a Folder in my Project called Images where i put the Image into

In my code, I put the Picture in a picturebox, so I load it into a `BitmapImage`

```
BitmapImage BI = new BitmapImage();
BI.BeginInit();
BI.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/ImageName.png");
BI.EndInit();
```

Comment: Shorter: `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/ImageName.png"));` No need for Begin/EndInit.