# WPF: ImageSource relative to executable location not project location

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, imagesource, imagebrush

I want to load image from an directory under my executable location.

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="WindowBackground" ImageSource="./backgrounds/Zenitsu.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

I have tried to use `./backgrounds/` or `\backgrounds\` but both seems like finding result in project directly instead or executables's location.

My output structure is like this:

```
Main.exe
----backgrounds
--------Zenitsu.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a converter such as:

```
public class PathToExecutableConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter is string path)
        {
            string rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            return Path.Combine(rootPath, path);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PathToExecutableConverter x:Key="PathToExecutableConverter"></local:PathToExecutableConverter>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="WindowBackground"  ImageSource="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PathToExecutableConverter}, ConverterParameter=backgrounds/Zenitsu.jpg}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

If the images will not change you might prefer to include them as embedded resources: [How to reference image resources in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552618/how-to-reference-image-resources-in-xaml)

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually they are all 4k wallpapers that really affect the load speed of my application.

Comment: You could look into asynchronously load the images when the application is started